# What is the difference between two connected slurs and one big slur?

Tags: piano, legato, slurs

I want to play this piece. This is the third lesson from the Bergmüller Opus 100 book and the piece name is 'La Pastorale'.

[image: two-slurs-connected-with-slur]

There is a slur for these notes: G,B,C,D and another slur for these notes: D,B,D,F,E,D.
When I see a slur on a piano sheet, I will play the notes legato and connected.

I don't know what is the difference if you connect all these notes with one big slur? And what is the purpose of this notation?

How should I play this and differentiate it with a big slur connecting all these notes?

Comment: Please add the name of the piece and the composer. That will help in the future if someone else has this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two connected slurs like this are effectively equivalent to a single slur.
This is bad notation practice, even though it's often seen.

Update: it's a misprint. The [first edition](https://imslp.org/wiki/25_%C3%89tudes_faciles_et_progressives%2C_Op.100_(Burgm%C3%BCller%2C_Friedrich)) looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Note that the edition posted by the OP diametrically reinterprets the phrasing shown in this first edition, throughout the page; in the first edition, the third bar of the second system is slurred, joining the three eighths to the preceding dotted-quarter, and so are many similar measures in the next system. The OP's screenshot, in the lowest system, breaks the phrase at the B, which is under a slur in the first edition.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a misprint, intended to be the same as on the system below.   Is there any pattern in the rest of the page to support this?

Otherwise, breaking the slur is meaningless.

So it's one sort of bad writing, or another sort of bad writing.

Comment: Yes. There are other parts as well in the piece which contains this pattern. Also, there are some parts with only 1 slur. So, I was thinking that there must be an intention to separation of these.